# Hourly pay for required pre-employment activities?

Tags: part-time, california

My son is starting his first part-time job soon. He was required to take a physical. He (and my spouse, as he's a minor) spent 6 hours (really) waiting at a clinic today to have it administered. The employer did pay for the physical, but he won't be compensated for the 6 hours.

This feels pretty underhanded, but common sense tells me they wouldn't be so stupid as to risk legal repercussions. I was wondering if anyone can add anything about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did the employer nominate a time and place for your son to go? Or did they leave it in your son's hands to organise the physical, just they paid for it.

Comment: He was required to go to a specific "urgent" care clinic. Quotes intentional there. They did not make the appointment (it was drop-in).

Comment: I would think that given your son was told to go to a specific place, the employer should pay for the time spent. Though your son should read their work contract carefully to see what it says about this. And others may be able to give you some specific knowledge of Ca law.

Comment: Could you have made an appointment? Did they tell you when to go (day/time) or could you have picked a less busy day/time? Are you aware that your son can be fired for asking, not asking, or any other reason not specifically protected or no reason at all under CA law?

Comment: You should reframe the question. Are you asking if it's illegal in California to require unpaid hours for pre-employment activities? Are you asking our opinion on employer practices? It's understandable to be irritated by a 6 hour wait time in a clinic, but you'll get better replies with clarity.

Comment: I can tell you that the FLSA doesn't cover this since he's not yet an employee.

Comment: @nvoigt in response to your query, they turned people away at the door, people with appts, because they were too busy. Yes, I'm aware that CA is an at-will employment state. Not that it's relevant to my question. Very helpful comment though, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a great idea for your son to start his first job with drama. As a parent I would want my kids going in with a positive mindset and just concentrating on working well and being nice to everyone. Not a negative mindset and a vague grievance.

So personally I'd just write this off to experience. The employer cannot be held accountable for the clinics workload and there was no appointment so the timing isn't under control either. So you may be able to create some waves, but what will that achieve long term, especially for your son?

Answer (score 3):

Just leave this up to your son. And that includes trying to influence him by talking about this. No need to make him look incapable by interfering with this. If he’s old enough to work, he’s old enough to handle this minor issue (if even that) by himself.

Comment: Just a word of advice. Start by assuming people are reasonable, and if they aren't, then feel free to give them all the common sense advice you've got chambered. It's generally off-putting to have someone assume you're going to take the most ridiculous course of action. Next time, if you're interested, ask if I have plans to sabotage my son's first job before assuming that was my plan.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman just a word of advice: you show up asking how this thing that is your son's should work, expect to get questioned why you're doing it and not him.  If you were told "he should be paid" what was your plan exaclty?  good grief.

Comment: @TigerGuy this is WORK stack exchange, not PARENTING stack exchange. FYI. What was the plan? None of your business, but it was to gather information. Even after being told, you folks still can't get past the idea that I'm some awful parent and by god, you have to do something about this injustice.

Answer (score 0):

I noted in a comment that federal law doesn't cover this situation. The Fair Labor Standards Act would only cover time spent on required testing while you're an employee; not before.

California state law talks about pre-employment testing but I can't find anything about payment for time. [The Department of Fair Employment and Housing](https://www.dfeh.ca.gov/legalrecords/?content=law#law) law section is mainly about preventing discrimination. In particular, I looked at [§ 11016. Pre-Employment Practices](https://govt.westlaw.com/calregs/Document/I0DAEEFAA9B5941D3B2583BD52A2C28F0?viewType=FullText&originationContext=documenttoc&transitionType=CategoryPageItem&contextData=(sc.Default)) and [§ 11071. Medical and Psychological Examinations and Inquiries](https://govt.westlaw.com/calregs/Document/I4174D84B5EDB4B359909BB5F302EB769?viewType=FullText&originationContext=documenttoc&transitionType=CategoryPageItem&contextData=(sc.Default)).

The latter does explicitly state that the employer can require a medical examination after an offer of employment is made.

I also looked at the [2002 Division of Labor Standards Enforcement Policies and Interpretations Manual](https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/Manual-Instructions.htm). And while [Labor Code § 222.5 – No Charge For Medical Examination](https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/DLSEManual/dlse_enfcmanual.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A156%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C57.36%2C705.36%2C0%5D) does state that they have to pay for the cost of the examination itself, it makes no mention of time spent getting the exam.

So while it's very possible I missed something, it doesn't look like California employer's are required to pay job applicants for any testing they do prior to the beginning of their employment.